# Webpack 2 - import throws error on postcss.config.js and other js files

Tags: javascript, babeljs, webpack-2, postcss

I have a project with Webpack 2, PostCSS, ES2015 (Babel) and Jest.

Right now, all ES2015 is working correctly on `src/index.js` and files directly connect to `src/index.js`.

But in some files it breaks the code. Example, on `mixins/index.js`, I have this:

`const postcss = require('postcss');`

And when I change it to this:

`import postcss from 'postcss';`

It throws this error:

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

The same happen in `postcss.config.js`.

What am I missing on Webpack configuration to make it work?

You can check the [repository here](https://github.com/sandrina-p/essencial-webpack2-boilerplate). These are the files I talked about: [postcss.config.js](https://github.com/sandrina-p/essencial-webpack2-boilerplate/blob/master/postcss.config.js) and [mixins/index.js](https://github.com/sandrina-p/essencial-webpack2-boilerplate/blob/master/src/styles/mixins/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

PostCSS requires your files to be in dedicated CSS files instead of `*.js` files like they are in your project.

If you want to use PostCSS with JavaScript (like with ReactJS inline-styles) you need the [postcss-js](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-js) parser which requires an additional [loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#js-styles) and a naming style like `*.style.js` so that webpack doesn't confuse the JavaScript styles with regular JavaScript files which are processed via Babel.

Comment: If you check my [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/sandrina-p/essencial-webpack2-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L36), you will she the loader there.

Comment: Hmm but i want to write mixins with js to have acess to js features, in this case, using es6 as well, that is what i'm trying to accomplish here

Comment: Maybe [free-style](https://github.com/blakeembrey/free-style) is what you're looking for? Haven't tried it myself, but postcss-js promises to work with it.

Comment: Not really. I'm pretty sure it's like what I have, I've seen another private projects working with ES6. The only thing missing is something on webpack config

Comment: The problem is that you're not saying what you want to achieve. CSS in JavaScript is a feature that works with technologies like ReactJS - but not on its own. This makes it really hard to help you here...

Comment: I want to make css mixins with javascript and unit test them. Like how [I explain here](https://medium.com/@a.sandrina.p/powerup-your-css-mixins-by-writing-them-with-javascript-825b41728a55#.v4hwyb8b4). It's already working. it's only missing the part of adding ES6 to mixinis.js